# Improve performance by using Flink instead of Kafka Streams when Source and Sink are in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams

Assuming I have input data coming in via Kafka topics, and output data to be sent to Kafka topics as well, under what circumstances would Flink be able to process data faster than Kafka Streams? At least when it comes to the time spent consuming and producing, I would not expect Flink to be any faster than Kafka Streams.

Comment: This depends on your business logic. If you have a need for stateful stream processing, I think this is where Flink outperforms Kafka.

Comment: @MartijnVisser If you happen to have more information on why and how that is, perhaps a link, I'd be curious.

Answer (score 0):

Both Flink and Kafka Streams are built on top of the same Producer and Consumer API, so they'll act similarly, up to a point. Once you get into the specific API/DSL, then the stacktrace gets more nested.

Outside of record serialization, Flink can perform more tasks like using Flink SQL compared to Kafka's KSQL, but in those cases, you're managing an external cluster.

Personally, I find Kafka Streams to be faster *to develop and maintain* because the application itself is the deployable unit, not something to submit to a pool of resources that might be preempted by some scheduler. But if you want to use more than a JVM language, then you will need to venture into Flink or even Beam. And those other languages will be slower because the code will then interface with those native Java libraries.